# Displaying json object attributes | Ionic Project and Laravel Restful Api

Tags: json, laravel, rest, api, ionic-framework

I am having trouble displaying data from an object, especially, its attributes. I made a http request to my restful api with my Ionic project **(cli 4.9.0).** He devolves an object and, when trying to display it on an html page, nothing appears.

First, here's what the object returned has:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Kit Kat",
            "barcode": "5000159020313",
            "created_at": "2019-01-24 23:15:21",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-24 23:15:21"
        }
    ],
    "msg": "Scan efetuado com sucesso"
}
```

Here's my code on Ionic:

- first I declared the variable resultScan

```
 options:BarcodeScannerOptions;
 scannedData: any = {};
 resultScan: any = [];
 idProduct: any = {};
 message: any[];
 TextMessage: string = '';
 ingredients: any[];
```

- then I put the data of the object returned by the request in
  resultScan.

```
    this.api.searchBarcode(this.scannedData.text).then((result: any)=>{

                if(result.data.length > 0){
                    this.message = result.msg;
                    this.resultScan = result.data;
                    this.idProduct = result.data.id;}
    }
```

- Then, on my html page, I tried to access the attribute name of
  resultScan, but nothing appears.

```html
    
   <div>
<button ion-button block (click)="scan()">Scan</button>
<div *ngIf="scannedData.text">
  <span>{{scannedData.text}}</span>


</div>

<div *ngIf="resultScan && resultScan.length">
    <div *ngIf="resultScan.text">
    <span>{{resultScan.text}}</span>
    <span>{{resultScan.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

I am unaware of what is happening, since I've had made other request and used the same logic to get to the attributes and everything went ok. This time, I cant seem to get anything of it, even tough I know that something is there. Is just not being displayed. I don't know if it's because the object is returned as a json object, or not. I need help like, for yesterday. Thanks, Carolina Ventura

Comment: Please edit your question and place and format your code on it, we do not use images in this case. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your two first screen shots everything seems fine.
But in your template, you need to loop through your array and read its properties like so :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="resultScan && resultScan.length">
    <div *ngFor="let scannedItem of resultScan">
        <button (click)="scan()"></button>
        <div *ngIf="scannedItem.text">
            <span>{{scannedItem.text}}</span>
            <p>scannedItem.name</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{message}}
    <div>
</ng-container>
```

I have put the message propety outside the loop as it will otherwise repeat as many times as there are elements returned in the array.
the **ng-container** will not render in your html. only divs if the service returns data

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I appreciate it. However, nothing showed up. I am pretty sure I have data in the object, as I have tried before writing in my html the following: '{{resultScan | json}}'. Here's a link with a screenshot taken of what was shown when I wrote the '{{resultScan | json}}': https://ibb.co/BLPhP30

Comment: can you please update your question and add your html template in full text?

Comment: Im sorry, it is the first time I used Stack overflow... is it better now?

Comment: You are trying to read properties that don't exist in resultScan such as text and name since resultScan is an array, not a plane object. Did you try my solution in your html ? it should work fine